# Pandas assign multiple csv values to list in single data frame column

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a csv file like the following:

```
#1, #2, #3, #4, #5, #6
```

I want to generate a data frame using the read_csv method, but how do I assign the values in the first 5 columns to a single column in my data frame as a list? And how could I apply a heading to that column?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new DataFrame.

Supposing your previous DataFrame object is `df=read_csv('something.csv')`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ColName1','ColName2']) #new DataFrame with column Names as ColName1 and ColName2
c=0 #Index for new DataFrame
for i in range(len(df)):
    df1.loc[c] = [None for x in range(2)] #Row elements initially Null
    df1.loc[c].ColName1 = []
    for j in range(1,5):
        df1.loc[c].ColName1.append(df.loc[i]['#' + str(j)])
    df1.loc[c].ColName2 = df.loc[i]['#6']
    c += 1
df1.to_csv('new.csv')
```

Comment: Is there no way to simply do that in a call to the read_csv function as parameters?

Comment: You can, but to be honest, it's not that simple.

Comment: Could I see it for my own curiosity?

Comment: Yes please. I just want to see how it would be done using that function.